# MySQL Query: Selecting rows of linked tables and catching a "bigger" dataset

Tags: mysql, dataset, row, create-table

I am trying to figure out how to build a query, which satisfies the following criteria.

I have two tables. Table `a` stores a list of authors. And table `b` stores a list of books. I have a linking table `c`, which maps every author to one ore more books. Naturally a book can have more then one author. Given a name (let's take name = "Douglas Adams") of an author, I know that if I do

```
SELECT * FROM linktable
    INNER JOIN a ON linktable.a_id = a.id
    INNER JOIN b ON linktable.p_id = b.id
WHERE a.name = 'Douglas Adams';
```

I get all the books which were written by Douglas Adams. Let us assume, Douglas Adams sometimes had "coauthors". How do I get them?

I want a list the somehow looks like this:

```
Douglas Adams, The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, maybe more details...
Douglas Adams, Book_2, maybe more details...
Coauthor_1, Book_2, same Details as in "Douglas Adams, Book_2, maybe more details..."
```

### Is this doable?

---

I have created 3 tables, which map what I want to store and what I want to retrieve.

The 2 storage tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UNIQUE` (`name`),
  KEY `name_INDEX` (`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name_FULLTEXT` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=932723 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin

CREATE TABLE `b` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_fulltext` (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1617432
```

and one third table, which links the 2 tables above.

```
CREATE TABLE `linktable` (
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `b_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `a_id_INDEX` (`a_id`),
  KEY `b_id_INDEX` (`b_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a2.Name, b.title
    FROM a
        INNER JOIN linktable lt
            ON a.id = lt.a_id
        INNER JOIN b
            ON lt.b_id = b.id
        INNER JOIN linktable lt2
            ON lt.b_id = lt2.b_id
        INNER JOIN a a2
            ON lt2.a_id = a2.id
    WHERE a.Name = 'Douglas Adams'
    ORDER BY b.title,
             /* Case Statement so Douglas Adams sorts before other authors */
             CASE WHEN a2.Name = 'Douglas Adams' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
             a2.Name
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. And it is incredibly fast. Wow!! Beats every expectation I had.

Comment: I adapted your conde snippet and it worked fine, but I must admit, that I couldn't figure put **why** it works. Would you be so kind and explain to me your approach? I am more interested in the way the `SELECT` statement behaves then in the "ORDER"-statement at the end. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Aufwind: I'll try to break it down table by table. The first reference to table `a` identifies the desired author - 'Douglas Adams'. The next two joins to `linktable` and `b` identify all books written by 'Douglas Adams'. The second join to `linktable` finds all authors for all books written by 'Douglas Adams' and the final join to `a` retrieves the names of those authors, which will include 'Douglas Adams' himself. Does that help?

Comment: That helped a lot. I visualized the relations on a sheet of paper, but I was not sure if I got that right. With your comment, I know for sure, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM b where b.id in(SELECT c.b_id 
FROM a,c
WHERE a.author = "Douglas Adams"
AND a.id= c.a_id)
```

Edit, Alternative:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A,B,
(SELECT c.b_id, c.a_id
    FROM a,c
    WHERE a.author = "Douglas Adams"
    AND a.id= c.a_id) X
WHERE b.id = x.b_id
    AND a.id = x.a_id
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! But I have still some speed issues. It takes 30 seconds to get me going. Is there a way to speed this up? The tables contain more then 5.000.000 rows...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, in is a little inefficient with large record sets, the alternative should be faster

Comment: Thank you for the alternative.

Comment: Favor to ask, I'm curious about a couple differences between Joe's answer above and mine. Can you run an explain on each select and post the results? I could dummy up the tables and do it myself but without a similar number of records I probably won't see what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @InvertedSpear: Sure thing! Are you just interested in the running time difference or do you want more details. The problem with the details is, that I didn't want to unfold my data here, so I altered the data and asked something similar, so I can extract the idea of the answer and adapt it to my problem. If you could be more specific I'll answer your questions gladly.

Comment: @InvertedSpear: Running Time Difference: Your "Alternative" works near as fast as the approach of Joe's. But I overlooked something. It does only return the books in. There is no trace of the authors. You remember: I was looking for all the relations (author ~ book) where the start is the name of an author with possible coauthors.

Comment: I was curious about row counts being returned and indexes being used, no worries if it would reveal any confidential data. I missed that your were also trying to get all the others, in which case, you would have to do all the looping back in Joe's answer. I'll add the same into my alternative example just so it's at least accurate if not as efficient.